# installing qt on raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, qt

I'm installing Qt to my raspberry pi-4 for image processing project. I use the commands:

```
sudo apt update
uname -a
apt-cache search qt5
apt-cache show qt5-default
apt-cache search qtcreator
apt-cache show qtcreator
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

it gives error saying that:

```
E:Unable to fetch some archives,maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: Did you try the fix?  Can you please edit your post to show the output of the commands?  If you use apt rather than apt-get it can give you more info (its better for command line use while apt-get is better in scripts).  Start with sudo apt update

Comment: Hi, I did the editing, Error still exists

Comment: What do you get from each of the commands?

Comment: Did you also see the note for qt5-default in the show: **This package should not be used for building Debian packages. Take a
 look at https://qt-kde-team.pages.debian.net/packagingqtbasedstuff.html for
 more information.**. Raspbian is based on Debian

Comment: The volume is high and can not be put in question

Comment: @HamidRezaTavakoli Hello and welcome -- Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=69163#p506401) out. You might be able to install `qt5` instead of `qt4` on this procedure.

Comment: hi @M.rostami, ok

Comment: What operating system do you use? Raspbian Buster?

Comment: yes. is raspbian buster, i use update of raspbiab buster and The problem was solved,thanks

Comment: @HamidRezaTavakoli, Please add "yes. is raspbian buster, i use update of raspbiab buster and The problem was solved,thanks" as an Answer to your question and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @MatsK, how to do it?  i don,t know

Answer (score 2):

I update Raspbian Buster and the problem was solved. From the original Author.

Answer (score 0):

Just type below command:

```
$sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

I think it will work for you!